# Disabling"Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I'm using Chrome to debug a web page, and while debugging I get frequent warnings and stops with the message "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."

I understand what is causing these, but they are in code over which I have no control. But their existence is making it hard to debug my code, as I have to click past twenty or so of these warnings to reach my code, and sometimes others are thrown during the execution of my code.

My question is: **How do I prevent the Chrome debugger from stopping on these warnings?**

Comment: Ugh, why would you use code with 20+ of these?

Comment: sometime there aren't other choices